# Racket: Map with keys/iterating?

Tags: indexing, key, scheme, racket, map-function

I've got some function `func` and want to apply it on a list `lst`, so I used `map` but I need to have the first and last element of the list evaluated with some other function `func2`.

So basically I want this:

```
(map (lambda (x)
       (cond [(isBeginningOfList? lst) (func2 x)]
             [(isEndOfList? lst) (func2 x)]
             [else (func x)]))
     lst)
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

How can I achieve this functionality?
Can I somehow get a key of each list entry? Like `lambda(key,val)` and then compare `(equal? key 0)` / `(equal? key (length lst))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `map` on all the elements except the first and the last one and treat those two separately. In this way you avoid those comparisons which you would do for every element.

```
(define special-map
  (λ (lst f1 f2)
    (append (list (f1 (car lst)))
            (map f2 (drop-right (cdr lst) 1))
            (list (f1 (last lst))))))
```

**Example**

Let's try to increment the first and the last elements and decrement all the others.

```
> (special-map '(1 2 3 4 5) add1 sub1)
'(2 1 2 3 6)
```

*Later edit*

I changed `(take (cdr lst) (- (length lst) 2))` with `(drop-right (cdr lst) 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

There's `for/list` with `in-indexed` and that does what you describe:

```
(define (f lst f1 f2)
  (define last (sub1 (length lst)))
  (for/list (((e i) (in-indexed lst)))
    (if (< 0 i last)
        (f1 e)
        (f2 e))))
```

then

```
> (f '(1 2 3 4 5) sub1 add1)
'(2 1 2 3 6)
```

Comment: it's equivalent it seems, but somehow it seems to me that `(for/list ([(e i) (in-indexed lst)])` seems better visually than `(for/list (((e i) (in-indexed lst)))` -- otherwise it looks to me like some brackets could be removed though they really can't be.